# ES6 function callback not working with Mongoose callback code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is some es5 code in a `pre` hook that works while saving a user:

```
// On Save Hook, encrypt password
// Before saving a model, run this function
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  // get access to the user model
  const user = this;

  // generate a salt then run callback
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    // hash (encrypt) our password using the salt
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }

      // overwrite plain text password with encrypted password
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my `es6` version of the same code:

```
userSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
  // get access to the user model
  const user = this;

  // generate a salt then run callback
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    // hash (encrypt) our password using the salt
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) { return next(err); }

      // overwrite plain text password with encrypted password
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

This fails for some reason and I don't understand why! There are no errors thrown. The user does not get saved with the hashed password string - just plain text.

If I change just the first line of code in the es6 example:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {...
```

the rest of it works

I don't understand if this is a problem with the way **mongoose** hooks work or am I writing **javascript** wrong?

Comment: this is due to line `const user = this;`

Comment: print this in both the cases and you will see the diff

Comment: Basically, the `this` for `() => {}` is the `this` of the surrounding scope. The `this` for a function can be manipulated by how the function is called

Comment: What @Gauravjoshi is trying to say is, in the first case, `this` refers to the callback function scope, while in the second case, `this` refers to the scope of the same closure `userSchema` is in. That's the whole point of arrow function - it inherits the scope of outer scope.

Comment: So how do I fix this in es6? Could you add an answer below with explanations?

Comment: fix by using `function` ... ... `()=>{}` isn't a ***replacement*** for `function`, it is a tool to use in the right circumstances

Comment: by the way, your es5 code isn't ... the concept of `const` confuses and angers es5 :p